# In a monitor for photographic work how significant is 3% additional sRGB coverage?

Tags: color-spaces, monitors, display, srgb

I am looking for a new display. Photography is not my professional occupation but a hobby, but I still want to have a good enough results.

After some investigation I came to following two displays models, the Dell [U2414H](http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/reviews/dell_u2414h.htm) and [U2415](http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/reviews/dell_u2415.htm).

The most important differences for my purposes are:

- U2414: 24" display and 96% of sRGB
- U2415: 27" display and 99% of sRGB

Both displays have the same resolution, so I don't see a significant advantage in 27" over 24" in this case. So, the mostly question is: how significant is 3% of sRGB?

Comment: It all depends on where your output is going. If the final display medium can't even show 96% there is no significance.

Comment: @MichaelClark At the moment I am not going to print my images (only for private usage). But I want get a peace of advise from people that actually know the difference and, probably, were in the same situation.

Comment: So how are you planning to view these images privately? Only on the same monitor as they are edited? On other computers/devices/smartphones/etc. you may own? Via social media to friends & family? It all makes a difference to the answer to your question.

Comment: @MichaelClark In general I want to be able to put my images on e.g. 500px.com

Comment: Anything internet based is dependent upon the capability of each viewer's display device(s), so the difference between these two displays is pretty much irrelevant in that context because you have absolutely no control over how the end viewer is going to see it. They may have a display environment worse than the 96% monitor, or they may have one better than the 99% one.

Comment: @MichaelClark I understand what you say, but supposing that viewer has an ideal display that can display every color existing, how critical it for a viewer if I will have 96% of sRGB during the editing?

Comment: The difference between 96% and 99% will probably not make any substantive real world difference. If the file is exported using sRGB color space, then all the sRGB colors present in the image will remain there and be displayed by a monitor capable of displaying all sRGB color values. When you are editing, those colors that fall between the 96% monitor and the 99% monitor will be shifted to a color your 96% monitor is capable of displaying. How it is shifted will depend on your color management settings and the active color profile but probably won't be noticeable to you either.

Comment: The only time it would make any real difference is when your image is substantially made up of many fine gradations of the 3% of colors that the one monitor can display and the other can't. And that is overwhelmingly not likely to ever happen by chance. You could set out to create such a file using some sort of graphics generator.

Comment: @MichaelClark Last two comments seem to be an answer on my question.

Comment: At the $300 level, just choose the monitor that looks best to you. It will be worth going to a retail store. sRGB is a relatively small color space. Even a $1000 monitor may only cover 99% of the larger Adobe RGB color space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When talking about the extent of a color gamut, all that's really talking about is the most highly saturated bright colours it can portray, which is only one small aspect of colour accuracy.

It says nothing, for example, about the monitor's accuracy in displaying whites and greys, its accuracy in gamma and its ability to portray skin tones, and other mild but important colours, or its contrast range.

96% and 99% are both close enough to 100% that the difference will be meaningless compared to other aspects of colour accuracy.

This is a CIE diagram representing colour as the human eye sees, only the brightest at each colour point (so we're not seeing darker colours here).  The vast majority of colours around us are concentrated in a small area around that white point in the middle.  The white triangle around it represents sRGB.  Circled are the reddest, greenest, and bluest colours sRGB is able to reproduce.  In this diagram, all colours outside that triangle are fake, because they extend outside the gamut of colours that the image - and the web - itself can reproduce.  As you can see, there are a lot of greens and blue-greens that extend outside sRGB, and these actual colours, which in nature these can be seen in things like butterfly wings etc, cannot be reproduced on an sRGB monitor or image, so the colours you're seeing there outside the triangle are not the real colours.  But I digress.

[image]

Any RGB colour space will be represented as a triangle in this space between a red point, green point and blue point.  The percentage of sRGB coverage will be calculated from the area of that triangle that falls inside sRGB, compared to the area of sRGB itself.  So as you can imagine, a triangle that covers 96% the area of that sRGB triangle will not look different enough to be significant.

Answer (score 0):

> What is a percentage of sRGB anyway?

These numbers are pure specsmanship.  Most look percentage of area covered in either CIE x,y or CIE u'v' ... whichever gives the bigger number.  The real way to compare gamuts is using total volume in a perceptually uniform space such as CIELAB. The author of this answer is correct that none of these gamut comparison methods will tell you which colors the device can and can't reproduce.  I suggest trying to find out the devices' primaries and comparing them on a u'v' chart with the understand that it isn't perceptually uniform and tells you nothing about the gamut volume.  Finger to the wind without real testing ...